# How to update tiles in windows phone by coding

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've written a code to get a news RSS feed for a specific university and I want to add a new feature for my application which is getting a notification if a new item added to the xml file ... if there is a new news:

[image]

can any one help me by giving me a sample code or project for something like this or any link for an article or tutorial ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`live tile windows phone` entered in your prefered search engine provides this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202948(v=vs.105).aspx

:)